# Bring implicit to scope

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a trait

```
trait Tr{
    def logic: Option[() => Unit] = None
    def apply(): Unit = logic match {
         case Some(l) => l()
         case None =>
    }
}

object Tr{
    implicit def procLogic2Opt(processingLogic: () => Unit): Option[() => Unit] 
= Some(processingLogic)
}
```

The thing is when subclassing the trait I have to import `Tr._` explicitly to bring implicits into a scope. Like this

```
import Tr._ //otherwise does not compile

class Trrr extends Tr{
    override def processingLogic = () => println("test")
}
```

Is there a way to do it without importing explicitly? How could I redesign it?

Comment: In your code in `Trrr` you are not actually overriding anything. `processingLogic ` is a parameter of `procLogic2Opt`. I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: These kind of things are a super code smell, you should just write `Some` instead of implicits and dealing with all this mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the headline question, if you really really really need it, move your implicit to trait:

```
trait Tr{
    implicit def procLogic2Opt(...) = ...
}
```

This is not always a good practice though, because it's hard to find which implicit is responsible.

A story: In my previous project we had Logging trait with implicit (kind of) `T => Any` which we inherited everywhere - imagine how many unexpected type conversions we had. Same goes for `() => Unit` as many people might inherit your trait without even knowing about your implicit and wonder why functions other than `apply` work when they shouldn't.

---

Besides implicit conversions (like your `procLogic2Opt`) are a **bad practice** as well (almost always).

Quote from [here](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala):

> Do not use implicits to do automatic conversions between similar
>   datatypes (for example, converting a list to a stream); these are
>   better done explicitly because the types have different semantics, and
>   the reader should beware of these implications.

More precisely about your case: [Scala Option implicit conversion - Bad practice or missing feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590756/scala-option-implicit-conversion-bad-practice-or-missing-feature)

Use implicit-classes instead:

```
implicit class RichSomething(something: Something){
  def toSomethingElse = ...
}

something.toSomethingElse
```

As mentioned in the comments your case is even simpler

```
Some(() => println("aaaa"))

class Trrr extends Tr{
   override def logic = Some(() => println("test"))
}
```

This will give you explicit, easily understandable and discoverable types without wondering how `() => Unit` became an `Option[() => Unit]`

Comment: It's bad even if this method is protected and is used only in subclasses?

Comment: Because the client is supposed to call only `apply`. I thought it's not necessary for subclassers to know that `Option` is required

Comment: @St.Anatario if you mean bringing implicit to a scope of trait, it's not commonly recommended - as it's hard to find where is that implicit comming from. For instance in my project we had `Logging` trait with implicit (kind of) `T => Any` which we inherited everywhere - imagine how many unexpected type conversions we had. Same goes for `() => Unit` as many people might inherit your trait without even knowing about your `implicit` and wonder why other than `apply` functions work when they shouldn't.

Comment: Understood. So explicitly importing it is completely ok?

Comment: @St.Antario The second part of my answer (and my comment-example as well) basically explains that it's very very recommended to make "implicits explicit", not just explicitly importing; in your case it should be `(() => println("test")).toSome` which is simpler to do with just `Some(() => println("test"))`. Reasoning is same: Imagine people wondering about actual type, or even trying to find your implicit from ` override def logic` line (let's say in IntellijIDEA) without checking all imports manually.

Comment: @St.Antario See this for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590756/scala-option-implicit-conversion-bad-practice-or-missing-feature

Answer (score 1):

> Because the client is supposed to call only apply. I thought it's not necessary for subclassers to know that Option is required

So, why require it?

```
trait Tr {
    protected val logic: () => Unit = () => {}
    def apply(): Unit = logic()
}

class Trrr extends Tr{
   override val logic = () => println("test")
}
```

(`val logic` to avoid recreating it each time.)

Comment: Don't quite understand. Maybe my Java-mind is the reason. I thought if we define val with a value specified it's similar to a static variable like in Java

Comment: No, `val` member just means "calculate it once during construction" (vs `def` which calculates each time it's called). Not related to static.

Comment: Bolshoe spasibo